# Merge two tables in containing all data R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

i have this two data.frame

```
df1 = structure(list(V1 = c("ASP28", "ASP28", "ASP28", "HSD29", "HSD29", 
        "GLN30"), V3 = c("GLN103", "ASP105", "PRO107", "GLN103", "PRO107", 
        "PRO107"), V5 = c(0.008, 0.484, 0.058, 0.008, 3.208, 4.616)), row.names = c(1L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
df2 = structure(list(V1 = c("ASP28", "ASP28", "ASP28", "ASP28", "ASP28", 
    "HSD29"), V3 = c("ASP28", "GLN103", "ALA46", "HSD47", "THR350", 
    "ASP28"), V5 = c(0.883, 0.158, 0.508, 0.025, 0.125, 1.391)), row.names = c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to merge them by adding a second V5 column (values from df2) if V1 and V3 are the same and adding  also the rows in which V1 and V3 are not the same putting NA where the data is not avaiable.
I've tried `dplyr:::right_join` and `inner_join` functions without success.

thanks in advance!

EDIT: here an example

```
V1    V3     V5.x  V5.y
ASP28 GLN103 0.008 0.158
ASP28 ASP105 0.484 NA
ASP28 PRO107 0.058 NA
HSD29 GLN103 0.008 NA
HSD29 PRO107 3.208 NA
GLN30 PRO107 4.616 NA 
ASP28  ASP28 NA    0.883
ASP28 GLN103 NA    0.158
ASP28  ALA46 NA    0.508
ASP28  HSD47 NA    0.025
ASP28 THR350 NA    0.125
HSD29  ASP28 NA    1.391
```

Comment: How about `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by=c("V1", "V3"))`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a `full_join`, not right or inner:

```
full_join(df1, df2, by = c("V1", "V3"))
```

Output:

```
      V1     V3  V5.x  V5.y
1  ASP28 GLN103 0.008 0.158
2  ASP28 ASP105 0.484    NA
3  ASP28 PRO107 0.058    NA
4  HSD29 GLN103 0.008    NA
5  HSD29 PRO107 3.208    NA
6  GLN30 PRO107 4.616    NA
7  ASP28  ASP28    NA 0.883
8  ASP28  ALA46    NA 0.508
9  ASP28  HSD47    NA 0.025
10 ASP28 THR350    NA 0.125
11 HSD29  ASP28    NA 1.391
```

If you want the `NA`s to always appear in the same column, you could also do the join manually by combining the two data sets, grouping by `V1` and `V3`, and then pivoting out the values

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) |> 
  group_by(V1, V3) |> 
  mutate(n = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n,
              values_from = V5,
              names_prefix = "V5.")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 4
# Groups:   V1, V3 [11]
   V1    V3      V5.1   V5.2
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ASP28 GLN103 0.008  0.158
 2 ASP28 ASP105 0.484 NA    
 3 ASP28 PRO107 0.058 NA    
 4 HSD29 GLN103 0.008 NA    
 5 HSD29 PRO107 3.21  NA    
 6 GLN30 PRO107 4.62  NA    
 7 ASP28 ASP28  0.883 NA    
 8 ASP28 ALA46  0.508 NA    
 9 ASP28 HSD47  0.025 NA    
10 ASP28 THR350 0.125 NA    
11 HSD29 ASP28  1.39  NA
```